# Alternate for environment dependent global variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

There are a couple of places in my Ruby on Rails project where I need to access a value dependent on which environment Ruby on Rails was started in.

Specifically, it is the name of the [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) database that I need to make a connection to.

Currently I just have something like:

```
MONGO_DB = "database_name"
```

in `config/environments/< environment >.rb`.

Then in the code I can call things like  `Mongo::Connection.new.db(MONGO_DB)`.

Is there a better way to do this without global variables? Just using global variables rubs me the wrong way, though they never change once the application has been started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully, there is a much better way. Find inspiration in *[YAML Configuration File](http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file)*.

Having all datas in [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) files is a really clean way to handle multiple cases.

Comment: Rails already has a configuration file for each environment, it seems like needless redundancy to add yet another file; that would be double-plus unDRY.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I really don't share your point of view, I've such files for my S3 and capistrano config for instance. For flexibility's sake, please don't invent rules.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean. You mean to set up a YAML file just for your MANGO configuration. I thought you were saying add a YAML file for all configurations that would be called by each environment.rb file. My bad. Edit your answer and I'll un-downvote it. I apologize for not translating what you were saying.

Comment: YAML files are a good solution; They're easily understood and are portable between languages. If you have DSNs for databases or set locations for data files, and need to share that common config info among multiple apps, then define a specific directory on the host for a master config file that contains the goodies. Also, if you have an event loop, you can check that file's last modified date periodically, and reload it if it's changed, allowing you to reconfigure the apps on-the-fly, rather than shut them down and restart.

Comment: Indeed, we finally all agree ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap your settings in a class or module:

```
module Settings
   MONGO_DB = 'database_name'
end
```

Then access it with:

```
Settings::MONGO_DB
```